# Bootstrap popover wrong placement when using select2

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, select, popover

I have set a popover to come out when you click on a day in my calendar (using jQuery FullCalendar), and it positioned fine until I added select2 to my form elements.

The problem is it should appear for the date 30, but it's positioning very badly.

Here's my popover code (select2 is initialized when the popover is shown) and a jsFiddle after this too:

```
cell.popover(
                    {
                        html: true,
                        title: '<div id="popover-head">Aggiungi Appuntamento</div>',
                        content: ['<div id="popover-content">',
                            '<div data-type="alert" class="alert alert-info hide" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">',
                '<strong>Usati: </strong> <span data-type="remaining"></span>/<span data-type="total"></span></div>',
                '<form data-form="shtoTakim" action="utente/shtoTakim" method="post" style="margin-bottom: 0;">',
                '<div class="controls controls-row">',
                    '<div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">',
                        '<div class="controls">',
                            '<select name="type" class="span2">',
                                '<option value>Seleziona tipo</option>',
                            '</select>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">',
                        '<div class="controls pull-right">',
                            '<select name="timezone" class="span1">',
                                '<option value="0">AM</option>',
                                '<option value="1">PM</option>',
                            '</select>',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="controls controls-row">',
                '<div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">',
                    '<div class="controls">',
                        '<select name="province" class="span3">',
                            '<option value>Seleziona provincia</option>',
                        '</select>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="controls controls-row">',
                    '<div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">',
                        '<div class="controls controls-row">',
                            '<select name="comune" class="span2" data-placeholder="Comune.." multiple disabled>',
                            '</select>',
                            '<input name="cap" class="span1" type="text" value="" placeholder="CAP" />',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="controls controls-row">',
                '<span class="label label-important pull-left hide" data-type="warn" style="margin-top: 6px;">Daily limit exceeded</span> <div data-type="spinner" class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-small">Aggiungi</button></div>',
                '</div>',
                '</form>',
                '</div>',
                '<span data-type="date" class="hide">' + cellDate.getFullYear() + '/' + (cellDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + cellDate.getDate() + '</span>'].join(''),
                        placement: function(tip, element) {
                            var $element, above, actualHeight, actualWidth, below, boundBottom, boundLeft, boundRight, boundTop, elementAbove, elementBelow, elementLeft, elementRight, isWithinBounds, left, pos, right;
                            isWithinBounds = function(elementPosition) {
                                return boundTop < elementPosition.top && boundLeft < elementPosition.left && boundRight > (elementPosition.left + actualWidth) && boundBottom > (elementPosition.top + actualHeight);
                            };
                            $element = $(element);
                            pos = $.extend({}, $element.offset(), {
                                width: element.offsetWidth,
                                height: element.offsetHeight
                            });
                            actualWidth = 410;
                            actualHeight = 200;
                            boundTop = $(document).scrollTop();
                            boundLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
                            boundRight = boundLeft + $(document).width();
                            boundBottom = boundTop + $(document).height();
                            elementAbove = {
                                top: pos.top - actualHeight,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2
                            };
                            elementBelow = {
                                top: pos.top + pos.height,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2
                            };
                            elementLeft = {
                                top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2,
                                left: pos.left - actualWidth
                            };
                            elementRight = {
                                top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width
                            };
                            elementBottomRight = {
                                top: pos.top + pos.height,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - (actualWidth * 0.8)
                            };
                            elementBottomLeft = {
                                top: pos.top + pos.height,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - (actualWidth * 0.2)
                            };
                            elementTopRight = {
                                top: pos.top - actualHeight,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - (actualWidth * 0.8)
                            };
                            elementTopLeft = {
                                top: pos.top - actualHeight,
                                left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - (actualWidth * 0.2)
                            };
                            above       = isWithinBounds(elementAbove);
                            below       = isWithinBounds(elementBelow);
                            left        = isWithinBounds(elementLeft);
                            right       = isWithinBounds(elementRight);
                            bottomRight = isWithinBounds(elementBottomRight);
                            bottomLeft  = isWithinBounds(elementBottomLeft);
                            topRight    = isWithinBounds(elementTopRight);
                            topLeft     = isWithinBounds(elementTopLeft);

                            if (above) {
                                return "top";
                            } else if (topRight) {
                                return "top-right";
                            } else if (topLeft) {
                                return "top-left";
                            }

                            else if (below) {
                                return "bottom";
                            } else if (bottomRight) {
                                return "bottom-right";
                            } else if (bottomLeft) {
                                return "bottom-left";
                            }

                            else if(left) {
                                return "left";
                            } else if(right) {
                                return "right";
                            } else {
                                // default
                                return "bottom";
                            }
                        },
                        animation: false,
                        trigger: 'manual',
                        container: 'body'
                        /*callback: function(){
                            $('.select2').select2();
                        }*/
                    });
```

I have recreated a jsFiddle with a button for you to check out, try commenting out the select2 initialization and see that it works fine without it. I have tried selectize.js too but it still gives the same problem.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qHQg4/ (adjust the button margins so the popover comes on top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the position because the position is based on the popover's dimansions and select2 changes that.

The proper way would be to style select2 ([check their documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)) and then change the positionning.

If you want a quick fix for positionning you can give the popover the dimansins it used to have:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHQg4/3/)

I only added the dimensions for the popover to the css:

```
.popover{width: 249px; height: 304px;}
```

Comment: if I do that, it'll mess my auto width and height for other popovers, any idea on how to set a width and height for this specific popover?